# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: addFontWeightStyle Error

Tags: android, xml, exception, classnotfoundexception, androidx

I am getting an exception which is thrown when I set the `contentView` of the `MainActivity` to the XML below. It already worked fine, but after some hours of implementation on other Activities I am getting this error. I cant reproduce the cause of this error. Maybe a change of min SDK Version or the implementation of a new library.

I am using the following libraries:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.3.4'
    implementation 'com.github.feeeei:CircleSeekbar:v1.1.2'
    implementation 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.igalata:Bubble-Picker:v0.2.4'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.arclayout:library:1.1.0@aar'
```

> 2019-03-01 10:09:43.145 32685-32685/ I/zygote64: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example -E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example -E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example -E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/s
>           2019-03-01 10:09:43.146 32685-32685/com.germany.alexander.example I/zygote64: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/s
>           2019-03-01 10:09:43.147 32685-32685/com.germany.alexander.example I/zygote64: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.germany.alexander.example-E2CMDM5ILl_awcv3JvuuHg==/s
>           2019-03-01 10:09:43.200 32685-32685com.germany.alexander.example E/TypefaceCompatApi21Impl: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
>               java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: addFontWeightStyle [class java.lang.String, int, boolean]
>                   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
>                   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
>                   at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi21Impl.(TypefaceCompatApi21Impl.java:74)
>                   at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.(TypefaceCompat.java:49)
>                   at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.create(TypefaceCompat.java:190)
>                   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:576)
>                   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:217)
>                   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:103)
>                   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:93)
>                   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
>                   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
>                   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1267)
>                   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1317)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:470)
>                   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
>                   at com.germany.alexander.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
>                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
>                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarSearch"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/search" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:backgroundTint="@android:color/black" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/your_placeholder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"></FrameLayout>

        <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: where is the xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is already tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124274577

> This has already been solved by https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/878553/ and is going to be available in a future release. Currently the exception is thrown but it doesn't affect the app (the typeface still loads correctly), everything should still work fine.

You can wait for a future release of AppCompat, go back to an older stable release or continue using this release for testing if it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 9):

In the app gradle file,

Replace:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

with:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

Comment: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01' is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with:
`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'`

Comment: latest version of now is implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'